# explicit работает на этапе компиляции или во время выполнения кода?

Tags: c++

Добрый день.

Заинтересовал вопрос того когда осуществляется запрет на неявное преобразование.
В сети написано:

> Стандарт C++ предлагает ключевое слово explicit как модификатор
>   конструкторов с одним параметром, чтобы такие конструкторы не
>   функционировали как конструкторы неявного преобразования. Однако это
>   никак не влияет на действительные операторы преобразования. Например,
>   класс умного указателя может содержать operator bool() для имитации
>   обычного указателя. Такой оператор можно вызвать, например, так:
>   if(smart_ptr_variable) (ветка выполняется, если указатель ненулевой).
>   Проблемой является то, что такой оператор не защищает от других
>   непредвиденных преобразований. Поскольку в C++ тип bool объявлен как
>   арифметический, возможно неявное преобразование в любой целочисленный
>   тип или даже в тип числа с плавающей точкой, что в свою очередь может
>   привести к непредвиденным математическим операциям.

Но из ответа я так и не понял, запрет осуществляется на этапе компиляции или во время работы программы (компилятора под рукой нет, вот сам проверить не могу). Когда осуществляется эта проверка?

Comment: Во время компиляции, конечно. Как вы представляете себе рантайм-запрет? Выбрасывание исключения? Слишком сложно для обработки. Undefined behavior? Хм, ну это могло бы быть вполне :-) Не, отлавливается на этапе компиляции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну прикиньте - ведь сам вызов для преобразования типов не генерируется, так? Когда может быть принято такое решение? только во время компиляции.

По-моему, ответ очевиден...